# Crystal Report Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I get an error with Crystal Reports. I downloaded the new Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2017, and now my application is causing this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Go to IIS, select your app from the list and go to Advanced Settings and change 'Enable 32-Bit Application' from false to true. Then restart and refresh it.

If it's already true or this isn't pertinent to your issue , try this [fix](https://forums.asp.net/post/2767592.aspx) regarding creating a bin folder with the dll's.

Comment: I was able to fixed it yesterday. I just reinstalled my crystal report. Thank you tho